# How can I efficiently clean text as a list of tokenized sentences

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, data-cleaning

This is an example. Say I have a block of text

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

paragraph = "There was a steaming mist in all the hollows, and it had roamed in its forlornness up the hill, like an evil spirit, seeking rest and finding none. A clammy and intensely cold mist, it made its slow way through the air in ripples that visibly followed and overspread one another, as the waves of an unwholesome sea might do. It was dense enough to shut out everything from the light of the coach-lamps but these its own workings, and a few yards of road; and the reek of the labouring horses steamed into it, as if they had made it all."
nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
```

output is

```
['There was a steaming mist in all the hollows, and it had roamed in its forlornness up the hill, like an evil spirit, seeking rest and finding none.',
 'A clammy and intensely cold mist, it made its slow way through the air in ripples that visibly followed and overspread one another, as the waves of an unwholesome sea might do.',
 'It was dense enough to shut out everything from the light of the coach-lamps but these its own workings, and a few yards of road; and the reek of the labouring horses steamed into it, as if they had made it all.']
```

were I to put the paragraph into tokenized words I could do all sorts of text preprocessing

```
word_tokenize(paragraph)

for word in paragraph:
    word.lower
    lemmas = [WordNetLemmatizer(word) for word in paragraph]
```

ect ect.

but usually these preprocessing methods take string inputs that are single words

How can I preprocess sentences and keep them in that data structure?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your expected output?

Comment: ["I am a helper. I told my delegates at the White House what to do."] -> ['i am a help', 'i tell my delegates at the white house what to do']